# render_views helper not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails, rspec3

I have a following method in my controller:

```
def create
  @job = Job.new(job_params)

  if @job.save
    render 'create_success', status: :created
  else
    render 'create_failure', status: :bad_request
  end
end
```

And here are my controller specs for this:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Api::V1::JobsController, :type => :controller do

  let(:actor)      { FactoryGirl.create(:user, :service_advisor) }
  let(:auth_token) { actor.authentication_token }

  describe 'POST #create' do
    render_views

    context 'with invalid attrubutes' do
      let(:job) { FactoryGirl.build(:job, customer_id: nil).attributes }

      it 'renders create_failure view' do
        expect(response).to render_template :create_failure
      end

      it 'returns 400 status code' do
        expect(response.status).to eq 400
      end
    end
  end
end
```

However, for some reason, no matter what i do, the controller spec allways thinks that this method returns empty response and status 200. I can test that method using postman or curl and it works as expected - return error messages and status codes (201/400) but my spec allways sees it as empty response with 200 status code.

It seems that `render_views` is not working. My env is:

ruby 2.0.0p594
Rails 4.1.0
rspec 3.1.5

Comment: can you add `puts(response.body)` after first `it`?

Comment: i've allready done that, it gives me `""`

Comment: if you add  `config.render_views` in Rspec.configure block nothing changes?

Comment: nope, it's still not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not given call to create action in your test case.

```
it 'renders create_failure view' do
    post :create, job
    expect(response).to render_template :create_failure
end
```

Comment: haha that's probably the most lame mistake i have ever made. Thank you Shweta!